# jquery 2 clicks to fire

Tags: jquery, events

I'm really struggling to find out why my jquery navigation is taking 2 clicks to fire when the page first loads. Its fine once you start navigating through the site. Its just when it first loads. Below is the jquery and the html nav.

I also have a fixed header to the page so and there was a margin of 79px

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var cccvvv = $(window).height() + 500;
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + cccvvv > $(document).height()) {
            $('.js-next').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('.js-next').css('display', 'block');
        }
    });
    $('.js-next').click(function (e) {
        var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
        var anchors = $(".js-list-item");
        var pos = anchors.index(selected);
        var next = anchors.get(pos + 1);
        var prev = anchors.get(pos - 1);
        target = $(next);
        $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
        $(next).addClass("js-current-panel");
        if (target.offset()) {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top - '79'}, 600);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.js-prev').click(function (e) {
        var selected = $(".js-list-item.js-current-panel");
        var anchors = $(".js-list-item");
        var pos = anchors.index(selected);
        var next = anchors.get(pos + 1);
        var prev = anchors.get(pos - 1);
        target = $(prev);
        $(selected).removeClass("js-current-panel");
        $(prev).addClass("js-current-panel");
        if (target.offset()) {
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top - '79'}, 600);
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>

<div class="nav">
<div class="container">
<a class="link js-prev js-scroll-to" href="#"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/up.png" alt=""></a>
<a class="link js-next" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/down.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have different approaches on `prev` and `next` links, which one requires 2 clicks?

Comment: Its next. The prev works fine.

Comment: Two thoughts: 1. Are you sure that you have `.js-current-panel` class assigned to some of `.js-list-item` at the page load? Due to a way your code works it may cause problems if it is not so. 2. Try to remove `javascript:void(0)` from your link or, even better, try to convert your `a.link` into `<button>`